# What's the first game to feature sacrificing at altars as a general game mechanic?

Tags: gaming-history

In *NetHack* you can sacrifice sufficiently fresh corpses at altars for various benefits.  Are there any earlier games where such sacrifices are a general game mechanic?  Going by the TV Tropes page on [Offerings to the Gods](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OfferingsToTheGods) *NetHack*, circa 1987, seems to be the earliest.

There's only so many games before then. [Pre-1980 has about 50](https://tvtropes.org/Main/EarlyVideoGames), and TVTropes knows about [500 between 1980 and 1987](https://tvtropes.org/Main/VideoGamesOfThe1980s).

(By "general game mechanic" I mean "excluding altar sacrifices which are done only to solve a puzzle and/or advance the plot".)

Comment: Maybe say that there's only ~50 games before the 1980s (https://tvtropes.org/Main/EarlyVideoGames) and there's only so many games before. Whoops, I added it. Delete it if you want.